# How to 'toggle' click multiple elements on page in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Lets say I have 10  with red color on my page, and they have same class which is called 'myspan'.

Here is what I want:
Click an element, and then the clicked one change its color to green.

what I did:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.myspan').click(function(){
            aaa = !aaa;
            if(aaa){
                $(this).css('color','green');
            } else {
                $(this).css('color','red');         
}
    });
})
</script>
```

This works! It almost achieve what I want. When I click one element, it changes to green successfully. But I have to click twice for another red element to make it green. I hope you guys know what I mean if you watch the code. Does anyone have any idea about how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a state for each span separately so instead of using a common variable you can use the .data() api like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.myspan').click(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            aaa = $this.data('aaa');
        aaa = !aaa;
        $this.css('color', function () {
            return aaa ? 'green' : 'red';
        })
        $this.data('aaa', aaa);
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Rxq7T/)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.toggleClass()` instead.Try this:

```
 $(".myspan").click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass("red");
 });
```

CSS:

```
 .myspan{ color: green; }
 .myspan.red{ color: red; }
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SF2U5/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

I would not use any variable, as long as your script's function is going to say that simple. Better try it like this:

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.myspan').click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass('color-red')) {
            $(this).removeClass('color-red').addClass('color-green');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('color-green').addClass('color-red');
        }
    });
})
```

CSS:

```
.myspan {
}
.color-red {
    color:red;
}
.color-green {
    color:green;
}
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2729p/

This saves the need to use a state saving variable and makes it more modular.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.myspan').click(function(){
            var colorVal = $(this).css('color');
            if(colorVal === 'red'){
                $(this).css('color','green');
            } else {
                $(this).css('color','red');         
}
    });
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off using `toggleClass`

`<span class="myspan">Test</span>`

JQuery:

```
$('.myspan').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("green");
});
```

CSS:

```
.myspan{
    color: red;
}
.green {
    color: green
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/haxtbh/E4txy/1/)